# Why the exe file of a new .net core console application is so big?

Tags: .net-core-3.1

I created a new .NET Core 3.1 console application, and did not modify the code (so it is only a hello world example).

I published the application into a folder with the following settings:

```xml
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <PublishDir>bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish\</PublishDir>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

After publishing, it created 5 files. The two interesting ones:

- `TestApp.dll` - 4608 bytes
- `TestApp.exe` - **174 592 bytes**

(Others are insignificant now: pdb, deps.json, runtimeconfig.json)

As I learned, the DLL file contains all my source code (I checked it with ILSpy as well). But why is the exe file so large? As far as I know, it should be just a wrapper that calls into the framework with the DLL file as entry point.

How can I reduce its size?

I want to make a simple utility application but it seems like the minimum size is 200 KB? That is absurd.

Comment: I don't think you can reduce it's size. This .exe represents the core "host". dotnet is open source, it basically contains what's in there: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/6072e4d3a7a2a1493f514cdf4be75a3d56580e84/src/installer/corehost https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6072e4d3a7a2a1493f514cdf4be75a3d56580e84/src/coreclr/src/hosts/coreconsole/coreconsole.cpp

Comment: @SimonMourier That is unfortunate. The same Hello World program compiled with .NET 4.8 produces an exe file which is just 4608 bytes, and no supporting .json files are required too. It's a shame that .NET core creates an executable 35 times larger.

Comment: @kaalus - .NET Framework has a runtime (120M) that must be installed on the machine too. Luckily it's installed in most Windows today. If you use the framework-dependent .NET Core or .NET 5 deployment, you'll have roughly the equivalent to .NET framework (the .exe is not mandatory you can use dotnet.exe) but you'll have to make sure the framework is installed.

Comment: Still, the application I created is "not self contained", meaning it should not contain the framework. It probably does not, but it is still unreasonably large.

Comment: @SimonMourier the 140kb monster HelloWorld executable produced by .NET 5 is not self-contained either. It still requires .NET 5 runtime to be installed. A self-contained Hello World is over 50MB.

Comment: @kaalus - I never said something different.

Comment: @SimonMourier Both applications are not self contained and require .NET 5 or .NET Framework 4.8 to be installed. Why 4.8 executable is just 4kB, while .NET 5 is 140kB?

Comment: Because .NET 5 is portable. The "loader" (bootstrapper, etc. call it the way you want) is included in the core "host" I gave the link to in my first comment while .NET Framework's loader ships with Windows (mscoree.dll, etc.) for a long time now. With .NET Framework V1 you had to install the whole redist size 23MB (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26) because it was not shipped with Windows